# Can Flash Builder with Flex mobile drag and drop controls for mobile apps in the design view?

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, flash-builder

I was investigating Flash Builder 4.5 and using flex for ios and android development.  Every demo I have seen uses the source code to demo the product development.  I noticed there is a design tab in flash builder.  Can you drag and drop controls and then capture events for a mobile app?

edit:  Why would you not want something like this:

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#interface-builder

I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

[This space intentionally left blank]

Comment: I know it's impossible for you to know, but why do they never show it?  Even in the adobe video showcasing flex mobile, it shows only the source.  Another video I saw said, "Developers shy away from the design view."  Thanks, btw.

Comment: If I had to guess; it's because most people using Flash Builder do not use Design View.  The developer perception is that design view and WYSIWYG editors create bad code that is not optimized and they can do much better by hand.  Design View is even going to be formally removed in the next version.

Comment: How can you see what you build and position things right on the screen?  That sounds counterintuitive.  I know you need "real" source code but initial positioning makes sense.

Comment: I can see them in my head if I need absolute positioning.  Or I can use containers that will position them for me (Form, VGroup, HGroup, etc.. )

Comment: do you have a linke that confirms they are removing it?  I can't imaging purchasing it without that.

Comment: It was announced at the Flex Summit earlier this week. http://www.spoon.as/2011/flex-summit-live-updates/ To quote: "removing unpopular and expensive to maintain features: Design View, DCD, and Catalyst workflows"